# Docker container behaving differently between different host machines

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container that me and a coworker build and execute in our machines. In my machine, executing a command in the container works, but the same command executed in my coworker's machine fails, even though we build them from the same Dockerfile and execute them the same.

How is it possible that 2 containers generated from the same Dockerfile behave differently? I expected that the containers having the same operating system and software installed, would behave the same.

My host machine is a Ubuntu 22.04 and my coworker's is a MacBook Pro (M1).

A bit more of detail, here is the Dockerfile in case it gives clues:

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -yqq upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y libopenblas-dev=0.3.13+ds-3 liblapack-dev=3.9.0-3 gfortran-10=10.2.1-6
ARG APP_ENV=local
ENV APP_ENV ${APP_ENV}

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN python mylib/setup.py install
ENV PYTHONPATH /app:/app/mylib

CMD uvicorn myapp.api:app --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --app-dir myapp --workers 12
```

It is build and executed like this:

```bash
docker build -t local/mycontainer .
docker run --rm local/mycontainer pytest -rA . --log-level=DEBUG
```

The error in his machine is this: `ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject`

And this is the `.dockerignore`, as that `COPY . .` looked suspicious to me at the start: https://www.gitignore.io/api/python,linux,osx,vagrant

The way we fixed the issue was by upgrading the version of numpy, pandas and scipy in his Dockerfile.

Thanks.

Comment: The are not entirely the same. M1 is ARM64 architecture, yours probably is x86_64. So docker picks different base images when you build your custom image.